# Using Git for an OSX application

Tags: xcode, macos, git, xcode4

I'm working on an OSX application (using xcode) and all the versionning stuff is managed with git. I'm asking because I'm a bit new at this (not git, but osx applications) : which files should be commited and which shouldn't?

I'm not sure what to do with the .xcodeproj and all theses folders...

Thanks!

Comment: WHat version of Xcode ? 3.x or 4.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `.xcodeproj`  directory you just want to keep `project.pbxproj` under version control. The other files in that directory are all user-specific - `project.pbxproj` contains all the important stuff.

Also you probably *don't* want the `build` directory under version control.

Answer (score 1):

In short, anything you feel you should be under source control.  Generally speaking, any files which relate to you only and no-one else should be excluded, as well as any files that can be generated/built from the files which are in source control.